# How to add a column filtering data from another collection in power apps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

I have two collections in power apps:

users:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBtbY.png)

colAppRoles:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gr6R.png)

And I want to add a column with the displayN of each role from the colAppRoles collection where appRoleId of users is equal to the id of colAppRoles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AddColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping) function will help.

1. Create a new Collection `colCombined`
2. Add a `role` column
3. Use the LookUp function to apply the appropriate `colAppRoles` `appRoleId` to the new `role` column

**Illustrated:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the AddColumns function to add a new column to your Users collection where you can use LookUp function to match the IDs and get the DisplayN values in the new column.